# How to make apex:details read-only?

Tags: button, read-only

I've got very simple **page**:

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c" readOnly="true">

    <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
        You are viewing the {!Employee__c.name} account.
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:detail /> 

</apex:page>
```

I would like to keep this page **read-only**. The problem is that on the **apex:detail** component are buttons like *Edit*, Delete and *Clone*. Using them we can modify our fields. 
I set **readOnly=true** on page but we still can change values of field by these buttons.

Is there any other way to make whole page **readonly**? (with buttons?)
Or how can i make these **buttons** **disabled**?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the "Delete" permission in a user profile's object settings, they will not be able to delete the custom object from any view.

Setup >> Manage Users >> Profiles >> (Profile) >> Object Settings >> (Your custom object) >> Edit >> Uncheck "Delete"

Alternatively, you can also "Override" the delete button with a Visualforce page that has an error message:
Setup >> Create >> Objects >> (Your custom object) >> Buttons, Links, & Actions >> Edit the Delete button

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this. The same user will have a choice to open readonly or editable page. So I cant do anything with permission and with overriding a button. But both ideas are interesting so thanks for them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `inlineEdit` attribute to false?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm

Comment: Yes, no changes. The problem is in these buttons (Edit Delete and Clone). We can still change everything using them

Answer (score 0):

This is your custom page. So you can use Javascript or Jquery to disable the button

```
 $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);
```

Pass id or class name. **It is a type of hack and in future may be stop working.** But for now it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following javascript solution which will remove Edit and Delete button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').each(function(){
         if($(this).attr('title')=='Edit' || $(this).attr('title')=='Delete')
             $(this).remove();
  });
});
```